# Yii2 not save many-to-many with new item

Tags: php, yii2, many-to-many, yii2-model

There is this code:

```
            $new_city = $request->post("new_city_select"); 
            $city = City::find()  //find item by name
                ->where(['=', 'name', $new_city])
                ->one();;
            if ($city == null) {
                $city = new City;  //if item not exist, creating new
                $city->name = $new_city;
                $city->save();
                $city = City::find()
                    ->where(['=', 'name', $new_city])
                    ->one();
            }
            $model->saveCities($city); //save relation
            $model->save(false);
```

If an instance of "city" exists, then the connection many-to-many create is normal.
But if not, then create a new instance of the "city" (in IF), but the connection is not established.
How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

from [BaseActiveRecord - link()](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord#link()-detail) you must link them.

The call to link() will populate the junction table.

I'm not sure but I think this can fix your problem:

add this after save()

```
$model->link('city', $city);
```